# Custom binding with data-bind on a template

Tags: knockout.js

I'm creating a custom binding to create HTML elements. My VM looks like:

```
function VM() {
    this.data = ko.observableArray(['one', 'two']);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="myBind: data"></div>
<script id="my-template" type="text/html">
    <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
</script
```

What I want to be able to do is create a new DOM element for each item in the *data* array. The issue is that the DOM element needs to have a data-bind to a template. Something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myBind = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()).forEach(function (x) {
            $(element).append("<div data-bind=\"template: { name: 'my-template', data:" + x + " }\"></div>")
        }
    }
}
```

Desired HTML output:

```
<div data-bind="myBind: data">
    <div data-bind="text: $data">one</div>
    <div data-bind="text: $data">two</div>
</div>
<script id="my-template" type="text/html">
    <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
</script
```

I understand that the standard foreach binding would do this pretty easily, but there's a problem with that binding when trying to display thousands of entries. The performance is horrendous and takes way too long to do that.

In addition, a solution I've found that works is this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myBind = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var html = "";
        ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()).forEach(function (x) {
             html += '<div>' + x + "</div>";
        }
        element.innerHTML = html;
    }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that in reality my template is much more complicated and writing a dozen or so lines of html in js seems like bad practice, difficult to maintain, and hard to read.

I've searched and searched and all the solutions I've found only get me like 80%. There's gotta be a relatively easy solution, right?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of data are you trying to show thousands of entries at a time of? Is it not something that should be paged instead? I can't think of too many cases where the user needs to see that many items at once.

Comment: Essentially, I have various filters set up so its rare that all entries are displayed simultaneously. I've only briefly looked at ko pagination so im a bit naive on that. 
Currently, when a user changes a filter and my ko.computed is updated, it takes several seconds for it to go through the foreach and create the new templates for each entry. Thats what I'm trying to fix.

Answer (score 2):

If we were to help you write this custom binding that uses a template inside, we'd essentially end up with the `foreach` binding. The only thing knockout's foreach binding does is wrapping the `template` binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['foreach'] = {
    /* ... */
    'init': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers['template']['init']( /* ... */ );
    },
    'update': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers['template']['update']( /* ... */ );
    }
};
```

<sub>[From the knockout source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/foreach.js#L3), some sections commented out for brevity</sub>

If you want to optimize for performance, you'll probably have to find another way. I've had some success with using the `visible` binding instead of moving elements in and out of the DOM, but it's really up to your specific situation.

Here's an example you can use to try out this approach. Whether it's faster depends on the complexity of the template and your browser. My anecdotal results that may guide you researching your own specific use case can be seen below. *Don't take these for granted, it's just one example on one machine!*.

```js
const filterValue = ko.observable("odd");
const pred = ko.pureComputed(() => 
  filterValue() === "odd"
    ? item => item.nr % 2 === 1
    : item => item.nr % 2 === 0
);
    
const items = Array.from(
    { length: 10000 }, 
    (_, i) => ({ title: `Item ${i}`, nr: i })
  );

const App = function() {
  const vm = this;
  vm.filterValue = filterValue;
  vm.items = items;
  
  vm.filteredItems = ko.pureComputed(() => items.filter(pred()));
  vm.isVisible = item => pred()(item);
  
  vm.visibleMode = ko.observable(false);
}



ko.applyBindings(new App());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="radio" value="odd" data-bind="checked: filterValue"> odd
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" value="even" data-bind="checked: filterValue"> even
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: visibleMode"> use visible instead of foreach 
</label>

<div>
  <!-- ko if: visibleMode -->
  <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text: title, visible: $parent.isVisible($data)"></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko ifnot: visibleMode -->
  <ul data-bind="foreach: filteredItems">
    <li data-bind="text: title"></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

### foreach

[image: Performance profile of <code>foreach</code> binding]

### visible

[image: Performance profile of <code>visible</code> binding]

Comment: After looking at the actual source code for the foreach binding I do agree that it seems to be identical to what I'm trying to do, but the actual implementation of it is slow. Writing my own html using $(element).append is only a couple hundred milliseconds for thousands of entries, instead of ~10 seconds using the foreach. Maybe the template databind is the part that's slow, and so my request by using a template would be for naught anyways.